# fixed column in bootstrap is not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make a fixed column (  header- containing a image) with full width using bootstrap. Below this column there is another row containing three column( another image in the middle div). When I run my code the things get messy and also other contents passes above the fixed column which should be pass below it. Someone please help me. I am new to bootstrap. Here is my code

```
 <div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">

  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
  <div id="header"><img class="img-responsive" src="images/profile.jpg"></div>
 </div>
 </div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-6"><img class="img-responsive" src="images/helpUs.jpg"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is CSS

```
.container-fluid{
background-color:#B8DB4D;
}
#header{
position: fixed;
   width:100%;
  background-color:red;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap has a convention for what you're describing, which can be accomplished by using the `.navbar-fixed-top` class on the content which should be sticky/fixed to the top of the page.

The only requirement for this to work as expected is that your `<body>` element has its `padding-top` property set to the expected height of the `.navbar-fixed-top` nav element. (in this example, the image 150px tall, so we set the body's padding-top to that height). This way, no content will be hidden behind the nav on page load (only when the user scrolls).

```css
.container-fluid {
  background-color: #B8DB4D;
}
#header {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
}
body {
  padding-top: 150px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=header%20img&w=350&h=150">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=other%20img&w=350&h=150">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=other%20img&w=350&h=150">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=other%20img&w=350&h=150">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=other%20img&w=350&h=150">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's really helpful. Thank You so much...! @pizzasynthesis

Comment: @Bera, if it answered your question, you should mark the answer as correct!

Comment: sorry, I am very new to stackoverflow. So, I was unaware of that and thanks for the correction.